# How can I merge and sum two dictionary key and items?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, sum, python-2.6

I have two dictionarys

```
dict1 = {
"list": {
    "alpha": {
        "a": {
            "score": 1,
            "visit": 2
        },
        "b": {
            "score": 3,
            "visit": 4
        }
    },
    "beta" : {
        "a": {
            "score": 1,
            "visit": 2
        },
        "b": {
            "score": 3,
            "visit": 4
        }
    }
}
}

dict2 = {
"list": {
    "alpha": {
        "a": {
            "score": 1,
            "visit": 2
        },
        "c": {
            "score": 5,
            "visit": 6
        }
    },
    "beta" : {
        "a": {
            "score": 1,
            "visit": 2
        },
        "c": {
            "score": 5,
            "visit": 6
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want to merge dictionary like this

```
dict1 = {
"list": {
    "alpha": {
        "a"  : {
            "score": 2,
            "visit": 4
        },
        "b": {
            "score": 3,
            "visit": 4
        },
        "c": {
            "score": 5,
            "visit": 6
        }
    },
    "beta": {
        "a": {
            "score": 2,
            "visit": 4
        },
        "b": {
            "score": 3,
            "visit": 4
        },
        "c": {
            "score": 5,
            "visit": 6
        }
    }
}
}
```

Condition 1. value is always new dictionary or int (not str)

Condition 2. If the same key exists at the same depth, the value of that key must be sum.

---

I think maybe I can solve this problem using for loops. 
But Python seems to have a simpler and faster way.

this is my best.

code:

```
def logic(d1, d2, inconflict = lambda v1,v2 : v1+v2) :
    for k in d2:
        if k in d1 :
            if isinstance(d1[k], dict) and isinstance(d2[k], dict) :
                logic(d1[k], d2[k], inconflict)

            elif isinstance(d1[k], int) :
                d1[k] = inconflict(d1[k], d2[k])
        else :
            d1[k] = d2[k]
    return d1

print logic(dict1, dict2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a recursive data structure; let's use recursion.

Edit: missed the python-2.6 tag, no dict comprehensions there. Edit2: Copy values in case they exist in only one of the two, otherwise you'll run into surprises with references to the same dictionary being inside two separate dictionaries.

```
import copy

def recursively_sum(var1, var2):
    """If var1 and var2 are ints, return their sum. Otherwise they are dicts
    and we recursively sum for each key that is either in var1 or var2."""

    if var1 is None:
        return copy.deepcopy(var2)
    elif var2 is None:
        return copy.deepcopy(var1)
    elif isinstance(var1, int):
        return var1 + var2
    else:
        result = {}
        for key in set(var1) | set(var2):
            result[key] = recursively_sum(var1.get(key), var2.get(key))
        return result
```